# Styling submit button not working. Rails + Devise + Tailwind

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, tailwind-css

I have an app with Rails + Devise + Tailwind. I have a form with this submit button:

`<%= f.submit "Login", class: 'w-full text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-gray-500 font-bold rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center mt-5' %>`

and it works well and if I try to change the font size it works, but if I try to change the background color to `bg-blue-300` or other different than `bg-blue-700` it becomes transparent.

I tryed to add inline style `style="color:red;"` and it works but we cant add hover background color with inline style.

I could create a `plugin` inside `tailwind.config.js` but that doesn't resolve why is that happening.

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly sure why this would not be working for you as I cannot recreate the issue. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/hcek39ou/1/) maybe the CSS is cached somehow? Have you tried closing the browser and reopening it?

Comment: Is quite weird that behaviour. I hve tried closing the browser, restarting the server, etc,... Also the I have checked if the file is covered by the content array and it is.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it, but I dont belive this is a good practice.

I removed from my css file `output.css` the default value for this this type of button (submit) and now is working

From this:

```
button,
[type='button'],
[type='reset'],
[type='submit']{
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 1 */
  background-color: transparent;
  /* 2 */
  background-image: none;
  /* 2 */
}
```

to this:

```
button,
[type='button'],
[type='reset'] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 1 */
  background-image: none;
  /* 2 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been a while but since I had the same problem I'll let my solution here:

At certain moment I've run `npm run build:css` which compiles my tailwind styles to `app/assets/builds/application.css` and minifies it. And this file is called in the `layout/application.html.erb`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
```

That was then conflicting with my current styles. Run `assets:compile` again solve the problem.